# Rewrite rules: Remove www | Enforce HTTPS | Append ?<number>

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to accomplish the following for my site:

- Remove www
- Enforce HTTPS
- Append *?number* at the end to enforce page content reload
- Use different 404 page according to language (en, el). Separate 404 pages have been already created

My .htaccess is the following:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI}?521 [NE,L,R]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

The behavior is the below:

1. The www is removed
2. HTTPS is enforced
3. The *?number* is appended ONLY if the url is **not** HTTPS
4. I cannot figure how to redirect to the proper 404 page. Please note that */el/* is part of the url if the selected language is Greek

Could you please help me with points 3, 4 above?

Thank you

Comment: Can you give an example URL for which 3) is not working as it should?

Comment: As for 4), what Apache version are you using? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument: _"From 2.4.13, [expression syntax](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) can be used inside the directive to produce dynamic strings and URLs."_ For lower versions, I don't know of any way to use anything like that directly with the ErrorDocument directive. It could easily be wrapped inside the `Location` or `Directory` directive of course to provide a different local path, but those can't be used inside .htaccess.

Comment: (If you have a physical directory `/el/` as the basis of your language switch, you could of course simply place another .htaccess into that directory, that just specifies the ErrorDocument.)

Comment: a) If the url includes the https in first place (https:// example .com
) the rules do not match so the the ?number is not appended. 
b) Apache Version 2.4.29

c) The extra .htaccess inside el/ subfolder did the job! Thanks!

Comment: Small correction regarding first point. The example is the following: 
a) If the url includes the https and does not include www in first place (https:// example .com ) the rules do not match so the the ?number is not appended

Comment: RewriteConds are joined by an implicit AND, unless you specify otherwise. Your 2nd & 3rd condition "contradict" each other when joined with the implicit AND, you got something that's never gonna be true.

Comment: I see, thanks for the tip. I 've tried several way but still haven't managed to make it work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi guys, any further input? Thanks.

Comment: Do you need this to be “dynamic” at all? As far as I can see, the `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$` line only serves one purpose here - that you have the host name with the leading `www.` cut off available in `%1` afterwards in the RewriteRule. So if you don’t need this to figure out the host name dynamically, you could remove that RewriteCond, and replace `%1` in the RewriteRule with the actual “static” host name.

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer for removing www and enforce HTTPS but thats it.
hope this helps.

#### WWW & HTTPS

```
#Remove WWW
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

#Ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```